# Camel SEDA Dismiss messages if the queue is full

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to use a SEDA queue (size 1) and I'd like all messages sent to that queue to be dismissed if it is full (silently, without throwing an exception).

Is there any way I could achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah there is no option on seda to make this easy. I have created a ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14235

Currently what you can do is to catch the illegal state exception and then ignore it, or in your camel route, you can do a doTry .. doCatch around sending to the seda endpoint etc.